$_POST data lost on htaccess rewrite when send via curl
I want to send a post request to an api file via RewriteRule. This is my .htaccess:
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^api/(.*).php$ api/request_data.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]

request_data.php is the only file existing in /api. All other file requests are to be send to this file having this filename (without extension) as $_GET parameter.
It works fine when I use an HTML form for testing as following:
<form action="/api/get_test_data.php" method="post" target="_blank">
  <input type="hidden" name="test" value="ABCDEF1234567890" />  
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form> 

This will give me in request_data.php:
$_GET = Array
        (
            [url] => sign_in2
        )

$_POST = Array
        (
            [test] => ABCDEF1234567890
        )

However, when I do the same via curl, it gives me only the $_GET param in request_data.php, the $_POST is empty.
These are my curl options:
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array(
    $curl, 
    array(
      CURLOPT_URL => "/api/get_test_data.php",
      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
      CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
      CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 1,
      CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 3,
      CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
      CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
      CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
      CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => ["test: ABCDEF1234567890"]
    )
);
$response = curl_exec($curl);   

Is it possible that the $_POST data is lost on rewrite when using curl, but not in case of the usual HTML form?

Looks to me like you are not really sending an actual HTTP POST request. Take a look at examples of that, those mention  the CURLOPT_POST option. So something like curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); ...

You are not sending any POST parameters with your cURL request, you stuck the data into the request headers instead. You should assign your POST parameters to CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS.

I found a solution to my problem.
I can get the $_POST data via getallheaders. Just need to clean up unnecessary information, but I can live with that.
